# Win32 C++ LVNI_PREVIOUS having no effect with ListView_GetNextItem()

Tags: c, listview, winapi, win32gui

I have a ListView where I need to perform operations on multiple selected rows. I start cycling through the selected rows using `ListView_GetNextItem(hLV, -1, LVNI_SELECTED | LVNI_PREVIOUS)`. However when debugging, the index of the first selected row is returned, not the last. This is the same when only the `LVNI_PREVIOUS` flag is used.

The MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-getnextitem) states:

> **Windows Vista and later:** Searches for an item that is ordered before the item specified in wParam. The LVNI_PREVIOUS flag is not directional (LVNI_ABOVE will find the item positioned above, while LVNI_PREVIOUS will find the item ordered before.) The LVNI_PREVIOUS flag basically reverses the logic of the search performed by the **LVM_GETNEXTITEM** or **LVM_GETNEXTITEMINDEX** messages.

Why would `LVNI_PREVIOUS` not work in the manner described? Could it be that I'm using the wrong `commctrl` [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-control-versions), as it does say Vista and above only?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I've never tried to use `LVNI_PREVIOUS` before. When iterating backwards, does using the ListView's item count as the starting index work, instead of using `-1`?

Comment: It doesn't: just returns -1.

Comment: Looks like they forgot to implement it.

Comment: The #define exists in headers before Vista; I think the reference to Vista is just them "updating" their docs. See e.g. LVM_GETHEADER, which also existed before Vista.

Answer (score 1):

I did a test on Win10 and sure enough, even though the documentation does not say it, there *IS* a dependency on ComCtl32.dll v6.

**WITHOUT** ComCtl32.dll v6 enabled:

- `LVNI_PREVIOUS` has no effect in `LVM_GETNEXTITEM`/`ListView_GetNextItem()`.
- `LVM_GETNEXTITEMINDEX`/`ListView_GetNextItemIndex()` do not work at all (the return value is always `0`).

**WITH** ComCtl32.dll v6 enabled:

- `LVNI_PREVIOUS` works in `LVM_GETNEXTITEM`/`ListView_GetNextItem()` as expected.
- `LVM_GETNEXTITEMINDEX`/`ListView_GetNextItemIndex()` work, too.

So, make sure that [ComCtl32.dll v6 is enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) properly (which you should do anyway, to get the best UI experience on Windows XP and later).

Comment: It seems still not working for me on Windows 10 with ComCtl32.dll v6 enabled. Could you share your working OS build version? `ListView_GetNextItem(hwndListView, -1, LVNI_PREVIOUS)` always return `-1` for me.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I tested using Windows 10 1607 Build 14393.1358.  But I also have XP and Win7 to test with, too.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if you can pick and choose controls from different ComCtl versions? I'd like to keep the 3D buttons for now but the newer calendar control I think is much better.

Comment: @SyntheticAscension use [Activation Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts) for that. Create and activate one AC to load ComCtl32 v6 and create the Calendar control, and then create and activate another AC to load a different version of ComCtl32 and create the buttons.